# NSTimer, setNeedsDisplay, unrecognized selector issues

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nstimer

The logic for this app is functioning, but the timer is not functioning properly. I have three files: ViewController.Swift, clock.swift, and clockstylekit.swift.

updateTime(), located in the clock.swift file pulls the time, breaks it into its components, and returns hours, minutes and seconds and summons drawRect to redraw the visual representation of the time.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

    class timeUpdate: UIView {

        func updateTime() -> (Int, Int, Int) {
            var date:NSDate = NSDate()
            var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)

            var hour = components.hour
            var minute = components.minute
            var second = components.second

            setNeedsDisplay()
            return (hour, minute, second)
        }
    }
```

The drawRect() method also located in the clock.swift file draws out the time components to a UIView:

```
class clock: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let (hour, minute, second) = timeUpdate().updateTime()

        switch hour {

        case 0:

            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas0()

        case 01, 13:
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas0()
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas01()

        .....etc etc
     }
}
```

This is the timer I am using:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

When I put this into the ViewController viewDidLoad function, I get an unrecognized selector error. When I place this into a function in my clock.swift file, I can compile without any errors, the time is updated properly, but it only runs once and does not update. Where should this timer go?

Comment: You should not be returning values from a timer. Just use the timer to cause a refresh of the drawing area and have the drawing area ask for the time. That way the time will always be requested at the point of drawing.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel So, the timer should have a selector that points to the drawRect or a setNeedsDisplay() function, and drawRect will pull the information it needs from updateTime()?

Comment: Just call setNeedsDisplay from the timer for the clock view. It should then have its drawRect called inside which you request the time which is what you are doing anyway it seems. See my answer.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel oh that's very interesting - it is definitely updating now after I threw the timer into the drawRect function and added Selector("setNeedsDisplay"). Sort of surprised that worked...only issue is that it is now looping in more timers. Sounds like I need to invalidate the timer somewhere?

Comment: The timer should be outside the drawRect. Add the timer to your controller. Think of it as a metronome creating a 1 second tic. When the timer fires, simply set the clock views display to need updated. In the drawRect when it is called by iOS just fetch the time and draw it. The timer is repeating, so only needs set up when your controller appears and deactivated when it disappears.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel If I add the timer to my viewDidLoad() in the view controller, it always gives me unrecognized selector errors (probably because it's a UIView function and not a UIViewController function). Adding it to the top level of the clock class just gives me a "Cannot invoke 'scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval' with an argument list of type..." type of error. Adding it to a function in the clock class or even outside the clock class doesn't provide any functionality. I also tried creating a class func containing the timer, with target: self and selector: Selector("setNeedsDisplay").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was place my timer in my viewcontroller like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("firedTimerMethod:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    @objc func firedTimerMethod(timer: NSTimer) {
        println("firedTimerMethod fired")
        let clockView = self.view as! clock
        clockView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

The timer's selector function needed the NSTimer parameter, the @objc, and I had to cast the variable as the clock class. Once I did these things, drawRect now properly updates each second the timer runs. I appreciate the help from everyone, all of the various clues got me on the right track eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If that `var timer = NSTimer...` code is in your ViewController function, then `self` is going to be the `ViewController`.  In your timer, you set the target to be equal to `self` so it's going to look for a method called `updateTime` in your ViewController, and it's not there because it's in the `TimeUpdate` class.  Also, your selector's signature is wrong.  You're calling `updateTime()`, but it wants to be calling a selector with a parameter of NSTimer that returns a void, so you need to call a routine with this signature:

```
func firedTimerMethod(timer: NSTimer)
```

Reread the description of `NSTimer` in the docs in Xcode.

Comment: Are you suggesting I nest the updateTime func into the firedTimerMethod? I don't see how I can properly return the 3 values if I create a function like that to return a void.

Comment: If you want to use NSTimer, you need to follow the documentation for it. You need to be more creative.  Perhaps you can call updateTime function inside your firedTimerMethod, and use the return values to update from inside the method.

Comment: That's really quite helpful. Something to try out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The signature for your timer function is wrong. According to the documentation the selector must have the following signature:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
```

So you need to create a timer method something like:

```
 func updateTime(time:NSTimer) {
    // your code here
 }
```

Then call it using `Selector(updateTime:)`

I would suggest that you simply have the timer request the clock display to refresh and in the display code calculate the time just before you display it.